How to replace undermount kitchen sink between plywood and stone countertop?
My sink is cracked and will need to be replaced.
Taking a peek under the sink, it looks like the original installers had plywood at the top of the cabinets, cut a sink and faucet sized hole in it, installed the sink, then installed the countertop on top of both.
What are my options for installing a replacement sink?



Stainless Steel sinks rarely crack.  A pic of the sink from the top may get more results. From what you show the counter top will have to be removed to replace the sink. However that may not be needed.

@RMDman added a photo of from the top and a photo of the crack.

oscillate out the plywood from the bottom or pull the countertop.  depends how picky you are as the countertop template is unlikely to properly match a new sink.  generally the countertop fabricator will waterjet using the sink template to get the proper bevels.

If I cut out the plywood from below with a multi tool, how will I mount the new sink and ensure it's properly supported?

@James you will use clips screwed to the plywood, possibly with spacers on the sink flange, in addition to the bead of silicone you'll run along the sink flange (after cleaning up the bottom of the stone where the old silicone was).

An undermount sink should be larger than the stone opening so you don't have a metal ledge showing, that stays wet and is hard to clean.
You have two options.  Both will require you to be lucky and find a sink with just the right dimensions, or to have one custom made.  Ya that's a thing.

Under - Cut away plywood from the lip of the sink plus a little more, enough to fit a larger sink of the correct size for the opening.  The new sink can be attached to the remaining plywood from beneath with common brackets made for that purpose.  Or if you remove more plywood it can be attached directly to the stone by professional countertop installers.  Obviously the brackets for wood are easier so find them and the new sink first and cut the plywood to suit

Over - Cut just enough wood to remove the sink.  Buy an over mount sink sized for the hole.


And a third option that may be cheaper.  Find a skilled welder to repair the crack and polish it nicely.

I haven't had to replace a sink like you need to, but I have had to resupport 2 sinks over the past 4 years. I was going to suggest using a multitool to remove the plywood too but since it had already been mentioned, I didn't need to add more of the same.
But the resupport, what I have done is after measuring the space between the cabinet and the sink side, which looks like it may be about 2 1/2" to maybe 3" Using a piece of plywood nearly the depth of the cabinet and long enough so when the edge is up against the sink edge there will be a few inches or more to attach it with screws to the cabinet sides. You will need the then add a 2X or other material, perhap a 3X4 if the gap is big. The plywood I use is 3/4" with my gap at 2 1/4", with the 3/4" plywood, I needed a 2X4 (1 1/2") to make up the difference.
Cut out the old plywood support so it is gone completely, otherwise it will be in the way for this "apparatus". The last piece of the puzzle will be the front and back supports, since the double bowl will only sag in the middle with no support.
Using the added pieces that support the sides, or you can use the cabinet sides too if you choose, cut 2 longer pieces of 3/4" plywood that will go from side wall to side wall, deep enough to get at least 3 screws into the bottom edge below the sink, the same as the sides, but I would put 5 screws in the sides.
The faucet side may give you trouble and you may need to use 1/2" plywood to keep room needed for the faucet. The plywood can be notched to allow for some room to allow the faucet to go in easier.


One of the sinks I did was mine. The contractor that installed the sink said what he did will hold up over the long haul, that was BS. Mine is a deep single bowl, so it only needed the side done. The other sink I did was a double bowl and it required the extra bracing.
